# How to create Account based Sync for specific app in iOS like android

Tags: ios, iphone

How to create Account based Sync for specific app in iOS like android. Which has to sync data in specific interval. and i think mailbox managed all things but How to Mail Box manage these all things, because in following path setting->mail->accounts->Fetch New Data-> given there we can  configure. 
How the Same thing i can achieve. any idea and thanks in advance for help.

Also i attached the MailBox Setting Screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpE4f.png)

Comment: use time class to hit api at desired time interval

Comment: @ museer Can you elaborate more your answer, i think you are telling about NSTimeInterval. If i am correct then time interval does not work in background. Please see the image which is of iPhone Mail app in Setting setting->mail->accounts->Fetch New Data->. I want to do something same like for my app.